# Why is the tick marker for zero after the bar in this qplot bar chart? 

Tags: r, ggplot2

Feature or bug? Why is it that the tick marker for zero projects is ***after***  the bar that represents the count for zero in this plot (instead of being in the middle as I'd have expected):

```
> qplot(projects,data=subset(df,projects<1000),geom="bar")
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this
```

[image]

Here is the data I am using:

```
      username gender   id   tenure  projects post
1      foo     male     123   1566      120   75
2      bar     male     456   1565       78    1
3      baz     female   678   1564       55    1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it appears to the left is that it putting the $0$ projects into a bin $(-33,0]$ which it then treats as negative.  To solve this you need `right=FALSE`. You could then have a similar problem at the other end with the $999$ projects put into the bin $[999,1032)$ which would appear above $1000$; so it would be better to have a binwidth which is a factor of $1000$ - I would suggest `binwidth=25`.

For example

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(projects = rgeom(10000,.005) )
qplot(projects, data=subset(df, projects<1000), geom="bar", 
       binwidth=25, right=FALSE )
```

produces

[image]

Comment: what is set.seed for?

Comment: @andresmh: so that if you run the script you get exactly the same result.  If you want new random numbers then remove it.